# Calculate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x \sin(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(x)+\sqrt{\cos (x)}}} dx $

Tags: integration

I tried to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x \sin(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(x)+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}} dx $$

I used WolframAlpha and got $0.8$ but I don't know how

Comment: Please try to use MathJax for formatting your questions. It makes it easier to read. See a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to think that there is no antiderivative for such a monster.

We can have a decent approximation of the integral building the $[3,2]$ Padé approximant of the integrand. This would give
$$\frac{x \sin(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(x)+\sqrt{\cos (x)}}}\sim \frac {3 x^2 (3 x+2) } {2(2 x^2+6 x+3 ) }$$
Now, rewrite
$$\frac {3 x^2 (3 x+2) } {2(2 x^2+6 x+3 ) }=\frac {3 x^2 (3 x+2) } {4(x-a)(x-b) }$$ where
$$a=-\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=-\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{2} $$ are the roots of the quadratic $2 x^2+6 x+3=0$.

Using partial fraction decomposition, we then have
$$\frac {3 x^2 (3 x+2) } {4(x-a)(x-b) }=\frac{3}{4} (3 a+3 b+2)+\frac{9}{4}x+\frac{9a^2(a+2)}{4 (a-b) (x-a)}-\frac{ 9 b^2( b+2)}{4 (a-b) (x-b)}$$ and we have very simple integrands.

Integrating, using the bounds and replacing $a$ and $b$ by their values, for the definite integral, we end with an explicit approximation which, numerically, is
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac {3 x^2 (3 x+2) } {2(2 x^2+6 x+3 ) }\,dx=0.842611\cdots$$ while the result of the numerical integration given by Wolfram Alpha is $0.833385$. So this simple work leads to an error of $1.1$%.